# Prevent i3 from moving icons from mate panel

Tags: mate, i3-wm, ubuntu-mate

I recently installed i3 on my Ubuntu Mate 15.10 laptop, opting to keep the mate applications panel. However I recently rebooted the system, and everything except the calendar and shutdown widget has been moved down to i3's panel/taskbar below. How do I move the widgets back and prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `tray_output None` for all bars in your `~/.i3/config` should have the desired effect. This setting disables the tray for the bars in question.

Example:

```
bar {
    # ...

    tray_output None

    # ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the information already present? Such as ip and disk space etc

Comment: No, the `tray_output` setting affects only the application icons. The status information is configured with the `status_command` setting. As long as you only add/edit the `tray_output` setting, the rest of your bar(s) should remain the same.